# Can I use Sqoop to import data into RCFile format?

Tags: hadoop, format, hdfs, sqoop

According to http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1764646

> You can import data in one of two file formats: delimited text or
>   SequenceFiles.

But what about RCFile?

Is it possible to use Sqoop to import data from Oracle DB into HDFS in RCFile format?

If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sqoop is currently not supporting RC files. There is a jira [SQOOP-640](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-640) to add this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1: Create a ORC formatted table (base) in Hive.
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  tablename (hivecolumns)   STORED AS RCFILE

 Step 2 : Sqoop import to this RC table using HCatalog tool.  
     SQOOP IMPORT 
    --connect sourcedburl
    --username XXXX
    --password XXXX
     --table source_table
     --hcatalog-database hivedb
    --hcatalog-table tablename
```

[ HCatalog’s table abstraction presents users with a relational view of data in the Hadoop distributed file system (HDFS) and ensures that users need not worry about where or in what format their data is stored — RCFile format, text files, SequenceFiles, or ORC files.]